# Firefox weird percentage height absolutely positioned div

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I have a pure CSS modal dialog set up like this

```
div {
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin:-26% 0 0 -26%;
  width:46%;
  height:46%;
  padding:3%;
}
```

This div displays centered in webkit browsers. In FF however, it's almost touching the top of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using margins, you could do:

```
top: 25%;
left: 25%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wwRUT/2/

I don't think I'd combine margins and fixed positioning.

Comment: That's the job, thanks. Any idea what the problem is? It's the same with absolute positioning.

Comment: I know with absolute positioning, the element is taken out of the normal flow of html, and basically sits on top of the other elements (I'm simplifying it). I believe the same happens with fixed positioning. The top and left values position the elements, but since they sit outside the flow, margins don't work with them. The browsers other than firefox may have been correcting for this? I'm not sure.